# why `.databases` attempts to write in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I am new to sqlite. I want to inspect existing read only database like below.

```
$ ll /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30445568 Jan  9 15:41 /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite
$ sqlite3 /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite
SQLite version 3.35.5 2021-04-19 18:32:05
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .databases
Error: attempt to write a readonly database
```

I don't get it. Do I need write access to simply query sqlite database? I need a few poiters here

Comment: Does it use WAL journal mode?

Comment: @Shawn It might. I don't know how to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I read in https://sqlite.org/wal.html about immutable query parameter. If I replace path with URI with that query parameter, then I can inspect the read-only database.

```
sqlite3 file:///nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite?immutable=1
SQLite version 3.35.5 2021-04-19 18:32:05
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .databases
main: /nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite r/o
sqlite> .tables
DerivationOutputs  Refs               ValidPaths
```